# -ExemptFromBlockDownloadOfNonViewableFiles $true not running on SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, document-library, error, pnp-powershell

I am trying to set this value true on my entire tenant for the ClientSideAssets library.

I would like to have `-ExemptFromBlockDownloadOfNonViewableFiles` set to true on entire tenant if possible if not how would I set it for individual sites? below is the PowerShell I am trying to run.

I used parameters from https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Set-PnPList.html

`Connect-PnPOnline -Url Tenant  -interactive Set-PnPList -Identity "ClientSideAssests" -ExemptFromBlockDownloadOfNonViewableFiles $true`

but when I ran the command, I am receiving the error below:

```
Set-PnPList -Identity "ClientSideAssests" -ExemptFromBlockDownloadOfNonViewableFiles $flase
Set-PnPList : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ExemptFromBlockDownloadOfNonViewableFiles'.
At line:1 char:43
+ ... "ClientSideAssests" -ExemptFromBlockDownloadOfNonViewableFiles $flase
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-PnPList], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Lists.SetList
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [PnP PowerShell changelog](https://github.com/pnp/powershell/blob/dev/CHANGELOG.md), `-ExemptFromBlockDownloadOfNonViewableFiles` parameter is added to `Set-PnPList` cmdlet in version **1.11.0**.

[Install newer version (1.11.0) of PnP PowerShell](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/articles/installation.html) and use it for executing `Set-PnPList` cmdlet with `-ExemptFromBlockDownloadOfNonViewableFiles` parameter